# Calling static method by object...!

Tags: java, static, static-methods

I have read somewhere that object cannot call static method...but according to below code `mm` object is calling `public static void main1(String args[]){}` static method and displaying output..can somebody explain it why?

```
public class Mainmultiple{
     public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
        Mainmultiple mm = new Mainmultiple();
        mm.main1(args);//here object mm is calling static main1 method..??
    }
    public static void main1(String args[]){

        System.out.println("Bye");
    }
}
```

When i run execute the above code i just get a warning message to either change the access of static method to `classname.staticMethod();` or to remove `static` modifier from `main1()`
But still required output still get displayed..so please explain the working of this approach

Comment: While I can take a wild gander what programming language this is (most likely java), wouldn't that be crucial information to add it as a tag?

Comment: @Xorifelse   yeah its java...sorry for not adding and thank u for pointing out..

Comment: You have read this nonsense where?

Comment: It's the other way around - cannot call non-static method inside a static one.

Answer (score 0):

We can access static method using the class name of that class and object of that class any where.
Because when we create the object of a class(whose static method you want to call) for creating object first ClassLoader load the .class file to JVM memory of Method area (in jvm memory it creates a Class object and stored it). So before creating object it is avaliable to ur class. When you create a object object is created in associated with that memory. So u can easily access static method using the object.
Have u ever noticed the o/p of referance of class....?

```
For ex A is a class
class A{
.......
.......
}
A a1=new A();
s.o.p(a1);
```

the o/p is something like this-
A@12f2312
In that hashcode two parts are there(A, 12f2321) one represent Class and other represents object. So we can access static method using object

Comment: Can u please elaborate O/p of reference of class?

Comment: [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java). is a question that why main method is static.? and by reading ques i am in a doubt that how jvm will create object first and then call main(); method which eventually will lead to extra memory allocation.

Comment: @shashimishra That is about three extra questions, but the fact that `main()` is static *eliminates* the need for the JVM to create an object first.

Comment: To call main() we dont required object. Because its a static method. We can call static method without the object of the class.

Comment: But jvm is able to call main method because When jvm instruct to the class loader to load a class to jvm memory 1st jvm creats a Class type class object and using that object jvm call main() a a thread not as a function.